# iAd giving error using simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, iad

In my app. i want to integrate iAd but its give me error like this

**EDIT**

Now i am tried with swift so i get different error like this

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "Ad was unloaded from this banner"
>   UserInfo={ADInternalErrorCode=7, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner}

here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        self.adBannerView.delegate = self
        self.adBannerView.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.adBannerView.hidden = false
    }

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return willLeave
    }

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        self.adBannerView.hidden = true
        print(error)

    }
```

I don't know what happened here.Anyone get this error and solve out please suggest me.Thanks.

Comment: It seems like your `didFailtoReceiveAdWithError` method has been replaced with the letter Y

Comment: Thanks for suggest.I replaced method with Y but its still giving error

Comment: Edited my question.Now i am using swift i still get this error :(

Comment: Please note iAd is shutting down at the end of June, and is no longer accepting new Apps into the program. You may be better off spending your time integrating an alternative ad provider. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: Thanks. so may be i upload my application into app store it will be reject by apple?

Comment: It will not be rejected, but your app will never display any ads.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a typing mistake. Implement

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
  // Hide Banner View
}
```